# How do I disable auto arrangement of website components on browser zoom?

Tags: browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, web, zooming

I am developing a website using Bootstrap v3.3.5. I want the website to zoom in and zoom out like it is an image and not auto arrange itself. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by disabling the responsiveness of bootstrap

**Steps to disable page responsiveness**

Omit the viewport `<meta>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Override the width of  the `.container` for each grid

If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.